# Can I bulk gecode addresses from local OSM tile server to get lat/long?

Tags: python, docker, openstreetmap, local, geocode

I need to geocode a few million addresses within a single country. I know that paid geocode APIs charge for bulk geocoding and/or place limits for queries. I downloaded a map tile server to run within a docker but would like to know how to get address lat/long.

I used https://github.com/Overv/openstreetmap-tile-server to set up the openStreet map tile server.
Is there a better way of doing this? I am using python-

Answer (score 0):

You did set up a local *tile* server, not a geocoder. To perform local bulk *geocoding* you need a local *geocoding* server. For an OSM-based geocoder take a look at [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/).